# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 vs. Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssms

I'm going to move to 2012 version of both Visual Studio and SQL Server.
Hence, I have a question related to comparison of VS2012 and SSMS 2012.

First-of-all, I've read the topic «[***Why should I use Visual Studio 2010 over SSMS for my database development?***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7599/why-should-i-use-visual-studio-2010-over-ssms-for-my-database-development)», but since they are talking about 2010, I would like to focus on new 2012 version.

My questions:

1. What exactly the difference between Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio 2012 in the aspect of SQL Server & DB management?
2. What is the gap, what can I do in SSMS 2012, that is not possible in VS 2012?

Particularly if I'm talking about the basic level of DB-creation & maintenance, should I install SSMS or is VS quite enough.

Comment: Usually, it is better to ask separate questions.

Comment: I've completely redesigned the question according to your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Totally agree with the post to which you linked.  What a crazy idea though, using an application IDE for database development.  It's almost as crazy as integrating source control directly into the IDE...

Comment: @Norla,
in the past I thought the same way, but now, when I tried VS2012, I actually didn't find any conceptual difference between VS and SSMS. Both of them allows DB-creation, edit, design change, query composing etc. So, now I'm thinking that if your position is not only DBA, but also APP. development, so VS2012 is enough. I'll be happy to see explanation why I'm wrong.

Comment: Because there are many dba-centric activities that you simply cannot do easily in VS2012 that you can do in ssms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd go with both, but I'm a DBA who is more focused on management-centric workflows. I'm less familiar with using VS as a SQL Server management interface, but looking at it, it looks as if you can do many things in VS that you can do in SSMS, but there are also many things you cannot do.

If you want to monitor replication subscriptions and other agent-based jobs, your life will be much easier with SSMS installed. Essential (and more advanced) DBA tasks are more readily facilitated by SSMS. Disaster Recovery, Replication, SQL Server Agent, Service Control, etc. These are all reasons to include SSMS.

They are not competitors, but tools created with specific purposes. If your job description dictates that both tools would streamline your workflow then by all means install both.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay with VS2010/SQL 2008 if i were you. I have a question open now because administering your SQL database from within Visual Studio 2012 does not seem to work as it did in 2010. There are no options for "Create Table" or "Show Table Data" the way there is in 2010 when adding a straight SQL Server Database (.mdf) to your project. You would need to use a seperate tool like SSDT or SSMS anyway.

Comment: As an update to this, It seems SQL 2012 turned out to be my issue. Using SQL Server 2008 R2 express with Visual Studio for Web 2012 works perfectly!